# Extract specific Value using match on another value from JSON array to JOLT

Tags: arrays, json, jolt

I need to extract the email address from value where "name":"username" from this JSON using JOLT:

I thought it would be

```
customer:{
      "*":{
           "name"{
                  "username":"email.@(2,value)
                 }
           }
          }
```

Input

```json
{
  "customer": [
    {
      "name": "title",
      "value": "Mr"
    },
    {
      "name": "address",
      "value": "park road"
    },
    {
      "name": "username",
      "value": "contactus@email.com"
    }
  ]
}
```

Expected Output

```json
{
  "email":"contactus@email.com
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just worked it out:

```
customer:{
"*":{
"name"{
"username":
"@(2,value)":"email"
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a spec containing such a conditional

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": { // represents the array
        "*": { // represents the indexes of the array
          "name": {
            // in order to pick the desired condition 
            "username": {
              // go 2 levels up and grab the value of "value" key
              // as roaming within each objects of the main array(customer)
              // [eg. reaching the level of the indexes of the array] 
              "@(2,value)": "email" //rename the key as desired
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

[image]